# How is the connection to fetch log files from Memgraph Lab working?

Tags: memgraphdb

I saw an information on [Memgraph's documentation](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/how-to-guides/work-with-docker#publish-ports) that the port 7444 in Memgraph Platform image is used for connection to fetch log files from Memgraph Lab (only in version 2.0 and newer). Can somebody explain how that actually works and what is it for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two protocols (and ports) that Memgraph supports which are: BOLT and WEB SOCKET. BOLT is the one on port `7687` that clients/drivers (including Lab) use to connect to Memgraph and execute Cypher commands. Port `7444` is a web socket port that Memgraph opens where you can connect via web socket protocol `ws` (or `wss` if the case of SSL) and listen for logs in real-time because Memgraph pushes logs to the web socket connection. Lab application will try to connect to that web socket port if connected, it will show the Memgraph logs in real-time.